# How to pick up activesync mobile phone number?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2013

Here is a cmdlet in powershell that can pickup all info of mobile device that connecting to exchange server 2013.

```
Get-MobileDeviceStatistics -Mailbox xxxx | select DevicePhoneNumber
```

I noticed that somehow, this cmdlet only pickup last 4 digits of Android Phone number, non of iPhone number got picked up...

iOS 7 and up

Android 4.4 and up

Some one knows why or is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I did some research for a similar question on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26937977/4241034).  It wasn't around the DevicePhoneNumber, but instead EASDeviceIdentifier, which prior to iOS 7 contained device serial.  It is up to the implementer of the ActiveSync protocol to decide what information is given to Exchange when a device is enrolled.  It seems all the mobile systems are moving away from using an identifiable piece of information and instead relying on a private-key sort of solution.

Here's what I could find on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg675595(v=exchg.80).aspx) regarding the protocol.  It seems that giving the phone number to exchange is out of fashion, though I cannot find information as to why this is.

Comment: I expect a nebulous "BYOD" is the answer as to why phone number is not given anymore.